# Need to get Sub to work in PHP

Tags: php

Is there an equivalence of html `<sub>` in php? I have looked for days now and can't seem to find one.
Anyway, i want to get results similar to commented result 3  and wrap it into a variable . Result 1 is a complete failure. Result 2 works but lacks my `<sub>`. Any insights?

```
<?php

$a = 'Na';
$B = 'CO3';
$B1 = 2;

$result1 = $a ?> <sub> <?   $B1 ?>  </sub> <?  $B ;
$result2 = $a .   $B1 . $B ;

echo $result1; 
echo $result2; 

// result 3
echo $a ?> <sub> <? echo  $B1 ?>  </sub> <? echo $B ;
?>
```

Comment: It's not a good practice mix up php with html directly. Look at @Phil's answer

Comment: @azuax Actually, I thoroughly recommend mixing PHP *echos* amongst static HTML. Makes for much easier-to-read code, especially when used with the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/alternative_syntax)

Comment: @Phil but one thing is to do an if or a for and other thing is to do something like the code of the question. Just for the record, I'm saying that your answer is the correct one

Answer (score 4):

Try [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
$result1 = sprintf('%s <sub> %s </sub> %s',
    htmlspecialchars($a),
    htmlspecialchars($B1),
    htmlspecialchars($B));
```

If your sole intent is to display this data within an HTML document, I'd recommend this approach instead

```
<?php
$a = 'Na';
$B = 'CO3';
$B1 = 2;
?>

<p> <!-- or whatever container element you want to use -->
    <?= htmlspecialchars($a) ?>
    <sub>
        <?= htmlspecialchars($B1) ?>
    </sub>
    <?= htmlspecialchars($B) ?>
</p>
```

But that's mainly because I hate generating HTML via PHP.

Should render as

> Na  <sub>2</sub>  CO3

Comment: Nice, something new to dig into.

Comment: @Edwinner *New*? `sprintf` and `htmlspecialchars` have been part of the PHP codebase since inception (well, at least since v4)

Comment: @Phil- I have never used it, but then again i started getting serious with PHP a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems confusing. To me, it should be formatted like I have it below. Remember, the `<?php` and `?>` demarcations are strictly to divide PHP from HTML. Within PHP you can echo HTML without issue.  Keep it simple in cases like this & only use `<?php` and `?>` to wrap code blocks.

```
<?php
$a = 'Na';
$B = 'CO3';
$B1 = 2;

$result1 = $a . '<sub>' . $B1 . '</sub>' . $B;
$result2 = $a . $B1 . $B ;

echo $result1; 
echo $result2; 

// result 3
echo $a . '<sub>' . $B1 . '</sub>' . $B;
?>
```

Also, you could use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) which I like to use for larger strings, but that is your own choice:

```
$result1 = sprintf('%s<sub>%s</sub>%s', $a, $B1, $B);
```

Comment: Great answer! The result1 above is what i was going for.